# Clicking on a value of the radio button in accordance with the sheet page - Java - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I read a value on the worksheet and select the same in a radio button on the page , using java and Selenium Webdriver?

```
   Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/plan.xls"));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);  
        int rowCount = sheet.getRows();
        for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){

            String nome2 = sheet.getCell(0, i).getContents();
            String Sobrenome2 = sheet.getCell(1, i).getContents();
            String tipo2 = sheet.getCell(2, i).getContents();
            String aparelho = sheet.getCell(3, i).getContents();

            driver.findElement(By.id("nome")).sendKeys(nome2);
            driver.findElement(By.id("sobrenome")).sendKeys(Sobrenome2);

            Select verificaOpt = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select")));  // as before

            String titleCaseType = tipo2.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + tipo2.substring(1);
            verificaOpt.selectByVisibleText(titleCaseType);

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            driver.findElement(By.id("nome")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("sobrenome")).clear();

        }
        workbook.close();
```

[image: sheet]

[image: page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a radio button with the value attribute :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='" + aparelho + "']")).click();
```

To select a radio button with the text content :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[normalize-space(text())='" + aparelho + "']")).click();
```